# Replace or delete double hash (##) in string in SAP/ABAP

Tags: string, replace, abap

I have a long string like this:

***Hello, my name is Bobby.##I really like Stackoverflow, but I don't like new lines in my string.##Best regard Bobby.***

I've tried to delete the double hashes from my string and replace them with a space but I don't know how to do it.

I have tried the following (and none of them are working out for me):

`REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '##' IN string WITH ''`   // nothing happend

`TRANSLATE string USING '##'` //nothing happend

`CALL FUNCTION 'SF_SPECIALCHAR_DELETE'` // input & export only 40 characters long

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm working with SAP NETWEAVER 7.5

Comment: Can you check the hexa value of the ## (in debugging)? It is most likely not a hashtag, but a line feed or something like.

Comment: Are you importing the text from somewhere? Is it a file from your unix? 
If its imported from unix it could be a character which is only shown as #.
#  are symbolies marker for example a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for this problem:

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>NEWLINE IN string WITH SPACE.
```

Comment: So  József Szikszai was right ! 
SAP shows non out of printable range chars as #.   So ## would been CRLF. Or 2 LF

Answer (score 0):

You don‘t have „a string like this“. You observed the content of the string by displaying it with [`WRITE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abapwrite-.htm) for which the documentation states:

> Control characters for line breaks or tabs are ignored in strings that are displayed using WRITE. These characters are displayed as #, like all other non-reproducible characters.

Apparently there are control characters or „other non-reproducible“ characters in the string that need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the underlying hexadecimal value of '##' in your string is not as straight-forward of double hashtags.

Try replacing `##` with `cl_abap_char_utilities=>cr_lf` or `cl_abap_char_utilities=>new_line` in the REPLACE statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
* --> Comment


* Storing the Input in a Program field 'str' using Inline Declaration, Which means it it Loosely typed
DATA(str) = 'Hello, my name is Bobby.##I really like Stackoverflow, but I don''t like new lines in my string.##Best regard Bobby.'.

* Replacing all the occurences of '##' in Program Field 'str' with space or ' '
* REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '##' IN str WITH ' '.
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF '##' IN str WITH space. 

* Writing the program field to Output
WRITE str.
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**